# Reusing ADO Command Object - Second Execute Fails

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ado

I'm attempting to reuse an ADO Command object to run the same query on multiple records from an excel sheet. As it stands, the code works when I delete the parameters and re-add them, but if I add the parameters outside of the loop one time and then attempt to change the values, I get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error on the cmd.Execute line. Strangely, the first time cmd.Execute is executed, there is no error. It is on the second attempt to run cmd.Execute that the error is thrown. I'm not sure why I'm getting this when I change nothing else except the constant deletion and addition of the parameters. Here is a snippet of the code in the form that fails, with the parameter addition outside of the loop:

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblSALES VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

trxLevel = conn.BeginTrans

With cmd.Parameters
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Customer", adWChar, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Item Code", adWChar, adParamInput, 8)  
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Start Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("End Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10)

    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Customer Sell-to", adWChar, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Invoice Id", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Invoice Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Order Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Order Number", adWChar, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("PO Number", adWChar, adParamInput, 100)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Trx Src Type", adWChar, adParamInput, 20)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Order Type", adWChar, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Invoice Dtl Id", adInteger, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Ship To", adWChar, adParamInput, 6)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Is Crossdock", adBoolean, adParamInput, 10)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Division", adWChar, adParamInput, 2)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Dept", adWChar, adParamInput, 3)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Sales Rep", adWChar, adParamInput, 5)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("PL2", adWChar, adParamInput, 2)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("PL3", adWChar, adParamInput, 3)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("PL4", adWChar, adParamInput, 4)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("MDSE Grp", adWChar, adParamInput, 5)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("COA Prod Cd", adWChar, adParamInput, 2)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Set Mdse Code", adWChar, adParamInput, 8)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Line Sub Pos", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Price", adCurrency, adParamInput)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Discount Price", adCurrency, adParamInput)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Qty", adInteger, adParamInput)
    .Append cmd.CreateParameter("Amt", adCurrency, adParamInput)
End With

cmd.Parameters("Start Date").Value = Trim(StartDate(1))
cmd.Parameters("End Date").Value = Trim(EndDate(1))

For x = 2 To lrow
    If sht.Rows(x).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        GoTo nextIter
    End If
    If sht.Cells(x, 1).Value = "TOTAL" Then
        GoTo nextIter
    End If

    For Each param In cmd.Parameters
        If Not param.Name = "Start Date" And Not param.Name = "End Date" Then
            If param.Name = "Is Crossdock" Then
                param.Value = IIf(sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value = "Yes", True, False)
            ElseIf param.Name = "Division" Then
                arr = Split(sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value, "-")
                param.Value = Trim(arr(0))
            ElseIf param.Name = "Set Mdse Code" Or param.Name = "Item Code" Then
                If IsEmpty(sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value) Or sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value = "" Then
                    param.Value = "(blank)"
                Else
                    param.Value = Left(sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value, Len(sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value) - 2)
                End If
            ElseIf param.Name = "Order Type" And (IsEmpty(sht.Cells(x, orderType.Column).Value) Or sht.Cells(x, orderType.Column).Value = "") Then
                param.Value = "(blank)"
            Else
                param.Value = sht.Cells(x, dy.Item(param.Name)).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next param
    cmd.Execute
NextIter:
Next x
```

Comment: Can you step through in debugger and tell us on which line and with which Param.Name it throws error?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, my apologies, I wasn't very clear in my post. No errors get thrown for any of the parameters. It's when cmd.Execute is reached for the second time that the error is thrown. For some reason, the first time cmd.Execute is executed it works.

Comment: Can you show us the first two lines of data that you are inserting?  It definitely sounds like a data error.

Comment: If you swap the first and second rows of data does it still fail on the second row?

Comment: Where is *dy* object defined? Please post full code even sample data for reproducibility.